# After install react native drawer navigation system not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

After install the react native navigation drawer and then if I run the project it occurs the error

`npm install react-navigation-drawer --save`

```
Loading dependency graph...jest-haste-map: Haste module naming collision: react-native
  The following files share their name; please adjust your hasteImpl:
    * <rootDir>\node_modules\react-native\package.json
    * <rootDir>\node_modules\react-native-navigation-drawer\node_modules\react-native\package.json
```

````
Failed to construct transformer:  { Error: Duplicated files or mocks. Please check the console for more info
    at setModule (C:\Users\pcadmin\workspace\mobile\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:620:17)
    at workerReply (C:\Users\pcadmin\workspace\mobile\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:691:9)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  mockPath1: 'node_modules\\react-native\\package.json',
  mockPath2:
   'node_modules\\react-native-navigation-drawer\\node_modules\\react-native\\package.json' }
(node:16708) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Duplicated files or mocks. Please check the console for more info
    at setModule (C:\Users\pcadmin\workspace\mobile\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:620:17)
    at workerReply (C:\Users\pcadmin\workspace\mobile\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:691:9)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:16708) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:16708) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.```
````